# How to delete table row which current selection in word by using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

The case is like this:My selection is two rows data in a table,I want to delete the two rows.When I use the below code,the content in the row was deleted,but the rows were still there.So,my question is this:How can I delete the full rows?Thanks.
And by the way,I use "bookmark" to operate the selection.

```
/// <summary>
/// Delete table row
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bookmark"></param>
public void DeleteTableRow(string bookmark)
{
    object oBookmark = bookmark;
    if (doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmark) != null) {
        doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmark).Select();
        object wdLine = WdUnits.wdLine;
        object wdParagraph = WdUnits.wdParagraph;
        object wdTableRow = WdUnits.wdRow;
        object wdCharacter = WdUnits.wdCharacter;
        object wdExtend = WdMovementType.wdExtend;
        object oCount = 1;

        Selection selection = app.Selection;
        selection.HomeKey(ref wdLine, ref nullobj);
        selection.MoveDown(ref wdLine, ref oCount, ref wdExtend);
        selection.Delete(ref wdCharacter, ref nullobj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similad issue, was need to delete unused table rows, went with this approach:
If you have "bookmark" that selects 2 Rows, you can delete them like this (at least in Word2016):

```
object oBookmark = bookmark;
if (doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmark) != null)
    doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmark).Range.Rows.Delete();
```

Seems works (at least in Word2016), but somehow my formatting was broked (that was a nightmare-template), then went with using "selection" (and it works smoothly):

```
bookmark.Select();
app.Selection.Rows.Delete();
```

Not sure from what version it works, but I'll leavi it there if someone encounter same problem.

The main pint that both Range and Selection objects have Rows property, that have Delete method, that works like "Delete Rows" action in Word.